# how to remove margin created by SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart, singlechildscrollview

I am using SingleChildScrollView() to wrap a column of containers. The scroll is working, but I get a margin on the top of my selector. The top white space is gone when i remove the wrapper SingleChildScrollView() .

[image: with white space]

this is without SingleChildScrollView() as you can see the white space above has disappeared

[image: no white space]

Can you please tell me how to remove that white space?

This is how I layout my code.

SingleChildScrollView -> column -> containers

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ViewModelBuilder<ReportViewModel>.reactive(
      builder: (context, model, child) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Waste Report'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const SizedBox(height: 5),
                      ToggleButtons(
                        onPressed: (int index) {
                          model.updateSingleSelector(index);
                        },
                        borderRadius:
                            const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        selectedBorderColor: Colors.red[700],
                        selectedColor: Colors.white,
                        fillColor: Colors.red[200],
                        color: Colors.red[400],
                        constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                          minHeight: 30.0,
                          minWidth: 80.0,
                        ),
                        isSelected: model.selectedPeriod,
                        children: periods,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: ExpansionPanelList(
                    expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
                      model.open();
                    },
                    children: [
                      ExpansionPanel(
                        headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text('Filter by Waste Type (KG)'),
                          );
                        },
                        body: Container(
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              ToggleButtons(
                                onPressed: (int index) {
                                  model.updateMultiSelector(index);
                                },
                                borderRadius:
                                    const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                                selectedBorderColor: Colors.green[700],
                                selectedColor: Colors.white,
                                fillColor: Colors.green[200],
                                color: Colors.green[400],
                                constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                                  minHeight: 30.0,
                                  minWidth: 80.0,
                                ),
                                isSelected: model.selectedWasteType,
                                children: wasteTypes,
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 20),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        isExpanded: model.isExpanded,
                      )
                    ],
                  )),
                ),
                Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            const SizedBox(height: 14),
                            AspectRatio(
                              aspectRatio: 2,
                              child: BarChart(
                                BarChartData(
                                  alignment: BarChartAlignment.center,
                                  titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                                    show: true,
                                    leftTitles: AxisTitles(
                                      sideTitles: SideTitles(
                                        showTitles: true,
                                        getTitlesWidget: leftTitles,
                                        reservedSize: 20,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    rightTitles: AxisTitles(),
                                    topTitles: AxisTitles(),
                                    bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
                                      sideTitles: SideTitles(
                                        showTitles: true,
                                        getTitlesWidget: bottomTitles,
                                        reservedSize: 16,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  barTouchData: BarTouchData(enabled: false),
                                  borderData: FlBorderData(show: false),
                                  gridData: FlGridData(show: false),
                                  barGroups: ReportViewModel.barChartsData,
                                  maxY: maxValue,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            LegendsListWidget(
                              legends: [
                                Legend('Cover', coverWasteColor),
                                Legend('Spoilage', spoilageWasteColor),
                                Legend('Preparation', preparationWasteColor),
                                Legend('General', generalWasteColor),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
                Container(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: const Text('Biggest Waste Contributor This Week'),
                    tileColor: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            const SizedBox(height: 14),
                            AspectRatio(
                              aspectRatio: 2,
                              child: BarChart(
                                BarChartData(
                                  alignment: BarChartAlignment.center,
                                  titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                                    show: true,
                                    leftTitles: AxisTitles(
                                      sideTitles: SideTitles(
                                        showTitles: true,
                                        getTitlesWidget: leftTitles,
                                        reservedSize: 20,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    rightTitles: AxisTitles(),
                                    topTitles: AxisTitles(),
                                    bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
                                      sideTitles: SideTitles(
                                        showTitles: true,
                                        getTitlesWidget: bottomTitles,
                                        reservedSize: 16,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  barTouchData: BarTouchData(enabled: false),
                                  borderData: FlBorderData(show: false),
                                  gridData: FlGridData(show: false),
                                  barGroups: ReportViewModel.barChartsDataTwo,
                                  maxY: maxValue,
                                ),
                                swapAnimationDuration:
                                    Duration(milliseconds: 1), // Optional
                                swapAnimationCurve: Curves.linear, // Optional
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      viewModelBuilder: () => ReportViewModel(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is the scrollView long enough? I mean do you have to scroll?.

This smells like Center is causing it. Try using alignments inside the column for managing the content and use a SizedBox instead of the Center of MediaQuery.of(context).size.height to be sure it fills all the space.

Comment: thank you @Over0n I fixed it by adding SizedBox..what is the difference between SizedBox and Center

Comment: Center is a bit tricky because its flexible, centers its content inside itself and also centers itself inside its parent, so it needs a complete sized definition in the parent. I don't know the academical reason why it works / not I know it from hands on experience... anyway in this case I think the real trigger of the issue was the lack of a fixed height so center would adapt to the minimum possible and then center itself inside the parent creating the gap.